# Is there a way to add repo to Snappy ubuntu core?

Tags: apt, software-installation, ubuntu-core

I am trying to install more stuff and I am seeing very little in snappy's install.

Is there a way to use apt-get or add repositories to install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, at the moment all you see is all you get. Snappy has just been launched, and it will take some time before applications get packaged for it.

As you can see, APT is not installed, and if you try to use `apt` or `apt-get`, you will get this message:

```
Ubuntu Core does not use apt-get, see 'snappy --help'!
```

`snappy` is the new package manager, and that is the one that you should use. In particular, `snappy` does not have the concept of 'repository': i.e. all packages come from the same source.

Comment: Ah, I am looking forward to get snappy on raspberry pi 2 and get lots of things going there.. Hope to see more things on snappy soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get apps that are not already packed as snaps (especially for arm platform) I am using classic mode installed by:

> sudo snap install classic --devmode --edge

then activate with

> sudo classic

then you can use the classic apt-get

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just create a snap from the ppa/apps you want.

Here is how I create an APT snap:

First you will need to install **snappy-tools** on your host system:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:snappy-dev/tools && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install snappy-tools
```

Convert APT packages into a snap by using **deb2snap** ,
more details please found here: https://github.com/mikix/deb2snap

```
$ bzr branch lp:deb2snap
$ cd deb2snap
$ ./deb2snap -d 15.04 apt
```

Install your snap:

```
$ snappy-remote --url=ssh://[user]@[target ip]:22 install apt*.snap
```

Make whole system partition writable,
which also means the system will be restored if you upgrade or rollback ubuntu-core, but apps installed by using snappy will remains here.

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Run the app: apt
Because a Segmentation fault, I cannot just use the command apt.apt, which we just installed, but you can do this instead:

```
$ sudo /apps/apt.sideload/current/bin/apt.real
```

and so you can start doing this:

```
$ sudo /apps/apt.sideload/current/bin/apt.real install software-properties-common # which gives you the ability to add ppa
```