# How do I add a text editor to a Ubuntu core, snappy system?

Tags: ubuntu-core

I've been trying out snappy. (http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/).I got the snappy image to boot up under virtual box. I see that it doesn't come with any apps already installed, which is just what I want. I like the idea that snappy encapsulates every installation, and makes it easy to undo my changes. But I can't find any apps except Hello-World and docker. Where are they? Is there a way to add an app from the standard Ubuntu lts distribution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to add repo to Snappy ubuntu core?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/577105/is-there-a-way-to-add-repo-to-snappy-ubuntu-core)

Comment: I think the last part of my question is more subtle. How can I package a standard Ubuntu app into a snap? (is that the right word?)